# In (the?) Mathematics class, I sit next to John, who is captain of basketball team

Tags: articles

> In **the** Mathematics class, I sit next to John, who is captain of basketball team.

We don't use article with the name of a subject so going by this correct sentence should be

> In Mathematics class, I sit next to John, who is captain of basketball team.

But what if I want to refer to a specific class then how will I say that ? We use article *the* to refer to a specific thing but since its incorrect to use *the* here how do I say that without using *the* with *mathematics*?

Answer (score 1):

When referring to classes, *the* is unnecessary because you only have one of that particular class, and you're not referencing a specific location/thing.

There are some examples when *the* would have to be used:

> In **the** Math **classroom**, John's desk is right beside mine.
>
> In **the first-floor** gym, there are trophies that John's team won last year.

Answer (score 0):

"In Mathematics class, I sit next to John, who is captain of the basketball team" is correct. The other form is clumsy English. You are correct about "the" being used to indicate specific things. However, they have to be uniquely individual and specific things. A mathematics class is a general thing that can be assigned individuality through context with possessives like "my," "mine," "yours," "his," etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to refer to a specific period of Mathematics class, you could say something like this:

`In the first period Mathematics class, MATH 101A, I sit next to John, who is captain of basketball team.`

Also, don't forget to include "the" before `basketball team.` We always include an article before this phrase, for whatever reason.